# Intersection of a convex set and a line

Tags: vector-spaces, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I am working on concave functions in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and one of the main results is a "reduction" one which allows to reduce the study of the concavity of a function of several variables to that of one variable. For this, we need to consider a convex subset $C\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and a line in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is a one dimensional subspace : $ A = \{  X\in\mathbb{R}^n : X= tV, t\in\mathbb{R} \}$. In my textbook, the intersection is represented by the following subset in $\mathbb{R}$ :

$$
\forall (X,V)\in C\times\mathbb{R}^n :  J(X, V) = \{ t\in\mathbb{R} \mid X + tV \in C\}
$$

My questions is the following : how can we see that it is indeed the intersection of $C$ with a line ? I mean, when I take $\mathbb{R}^3$ to have a picture I see that this intersection is also a line so it is a one dimensional space, however this intersection should be composed of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whereas the set $J(X,V)$ is in $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, I don't see where the condition $X+  tV\in C$ comes from ?

Thinking on that, I thought the set $J(X,V)$ is a way to identify each vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is both in $C$ and in $A$ since it is necessarly of the form $tV$... but I did not managed to find why the condition $X+  tV\in C$, is it something like if $X\in C$ and $X+tV\in C$ it implies that $tV\in C$ ? But I am not able to see why it should be true in general if we don't have a vector subspace structure (stable by the addition of a vector).

Please let me know where I am wrong and thank you a lot.

Comment: Your definition of the set $tV$ looks messed up. Please double check it.

Comment: @Digitallis Thank you for your comment ! However I don’t see what is wrong in my definition of $tV$ ? It is the set of all vectors that are colinear with V if we take $\mathbb{R}^3$ as visual representation so they are of the form $t\times V$ no ?

Comment: It is self referencing.  You have $tV$ on both the left and the right hand side of the equality defining $tV$. This makes everything confusing because you are using the character $t$ in two ways once as a symbol in $tV$ to denote a specific set but also as a real number in $tV$ i.e. $t$ times $V$. This is confusing.

Comment: @Digitallis You're right, I have changed this.